# How to fix dual boot Ubuntu/Win 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb

I installed Ubuntu along Windows 10 on my Acer PC.

When I first inserted USB into the pc, I couldn't change the boot order and boot from it before I changed BIOS into legacy from UEFI. In Legacy mode I installed the Ubuntu.

Now I don't have the boot menu to choose from, it boots automatically to ubuntu if bios is set to legacy mode, and it boots automatically to windows if bios is set to UEFI mode. No way to boot from USB anymore. I inserted USB to perform a memory scan, but it boots directly to windows/ubuntu for some reason.

Can someone explain why boot choice is not offered anywhere and how I can fix this now?

Answer (score 0):

In order to boot in UEFI Mode there has to be an EFI System partition on USB or Hard Disk and it should use GPT Partition Scheme. The EFI System partition should be FAT32 (Maximum compatibility). Other file systems are supported only if manufacturer implemented it in the firmware.

You have installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode and Windows 10 in UEFI mode. Ubuntu did not create an EFI partition so you are unable to boot Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

From the answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/935838/986837 by Rod Smith

> On most computers, two OSes don't have to be in the same boot mode,
>   but it's helpful -- very helpful -- for both of them to be in the same
>   boot mode.
>
> Details vary greatly from one EFI to another, but in all but some
>   very ancient EFIs, BIOS-mode OSes are installed using a Compatibility
>   Support Module (CSM), which is a sort of BIOS emulator for EFI
>   firmware. The CSM can be switched on and off, either by you setting
>   options in the firmware or by the firmware itself, when it detects
>   whatever key things trigger it to use the CSM or not use it.
>   Unfortunately, there's very little standardization in the way
>   different EFIs (and therefore computers) determine which boot mode to
>   use when both are active. This makes the CSM a temperamental and
>   tricky thing to use. That said, there are typically two ways that OSes
>   using different boot modes can be managed:
>
> - Using the built-in boot manager -- All EFIs provide some sort of built-in boot manager, but details on how they're used vary from one
>     machine to another. Typically, you access the boot manager by hitting
>     a function key (usually F8 or above), Del, or Enter soon after the
>     computer powers on. This action produces a menu of boot options. Some
>     of these will boot the computer in EFI mode and others in BIOS mode.
>     EFI entries are usually either named by the OS that installs them
>     (e.g., ubuntu or Windows boot manager) or include the string "UEFI."
>     BIOS entries are likely to describe BIOS boot media, like be the name
>     of a hard disk. Thus, you can switch between a BIOS-mode Windows and
>     an EFI-mode Ubuntu by selecting the hard disk by name vs. an entry
>     called ubuntu in the boot manager.
> - Using rEFInd -- My rEFInd boot manager is a standalone boot manager that can do something similar to what the EFI's boot manager can do,
>     but it works in more-or-less the same way on any EFI-based computer.
>     (Macs are an exception; the CSM in Macs is unique, and so rEFInd
>     treats Macs differently.) By default, rEFInd's CSM support is
>     inactive, so you won't see BIOS-mode boot options. If you uncomment
>     the scanfor line in refind.conf and ensure that hdbios is among the
>     options, you'll see a gray diamond-shaped icon for your hard disk,
>     which will launch any BIOS-mode boot loader it contains. This is in
>     addition to whatever EFI-mode boot loaders the disk contains. Thus,
>     you can switch between BIOS-mode and EFI-mode boot loaders.

Using rEFInd boot manager can work but in your case it would be better to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Reinstall Ubuntu (Replaces Windows Boot Loader with GRUB) :

1. Create USB Installer for Ubuntu in Rufus. Select GPT Partition Scheme and Target System UEFI. It will create EFI Partition for Ubuntu Setup to boot in UEFI mode.
2. Switch your bios to UEFI Mode then save and reset.
3. Boot from USB
4. In the partitioning section of setup select manual.
5. Delete partitions created by previous Ubuntu installation and already existing fat32 efi partition created by Windows
6. Create new FAT32 partition and set "USE AS : EFI".
7. Create new partition for Ubuntu (ext4).
8. Install

The setup should detect the existing Windows Installation and when you reboot you will be presented with grub bootloader.

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable replacing Windows Bootloader then you can create a separate EFI partition for Ubuntu and remove Windows EFI partition later.

Comment: Hi, your answer makes perfect sense except for the 2nd and 3rd step. As I stated above, I couldn't get to boot from the USB before enabling legacy boot, this was the main problem. The PC will only boot to USB when on legacy mode. This still happens, even though USB is the first option in the UEFI boot menu, it boots straight to windows, so I can't access the USB at all.

Comment: Which application did you use to create the USB ? Did the USB have the EFI Partition the first time ? As I have already written in the answer, In order to boot from USB in UEFI mode (Legacy mode Disabled) you need to have FAT32 EFI Partition on USB which is created automatically if you use Rufus. So recreate the Install USB for UEFI mode (First Step) and install Ubuntu again in UEFI mode. Both USB Install Media and the Operating System need the EFI Partition.